# read input and run based on if condition in .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to automate the creation and deletion of user accounts on the Kubernetes cluster environment. I plan to use the GitLab CI/CD way to do this using a base docker image and placing the manager account config under ~/.kube/config path in it and use that manager account to create/delete accounts on the Kubernetes environment.

Basically, I have both production and the staging Kubernetes cluster environment. I want to do the same action in both environments, whenever a staff joins or leaves.

In .gitlab-ci.yml, under "before_script:", I want to add one condition like:

if the input value is "stage", I want to execute:

`echo -n $KUBECTL_STAGING | base64 -d > ~/.kube/config`

if the input value is "prod", I want to execute:

`echo -n $KUBECTL_PRODUCTION | base64 -d > ~/.kube/config`

How to accept input like this and run based on the if condition in .gitlab-ci.yml ?.

Comment: What do you mean by "input value" ? Gitlab pipelines are triggered by pushes on git references such as branches or tags.

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner at this. I asked it in a general term. Do you know a workaround for this? Because I have two cluster env, staging, and production. How can I implement it in one .gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: If you set a Gitlab pipeline job's `when` to `manual`, you can manually trigger it via UI and also provide some input variables to the Job. In your job script, just use the input variable value to decide.